# How do I record the history of what happened while using sort in python for one string, and apply that to other strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

```
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
   lst = list(f.readline().strip())
   sortedLst = sorted(lst, key = lambda x: (x.lower(), x.swapcase()))

print(lst)
print(sortedLst)
```

The word I am using as an example is 'ThatCcer'.
My outputs are ['T', 'h', 'a', 't', 'C', 'c', 'e', 'r'] for lst and my outputs are ['a', 'c', 'C', 'e', 'h', 'r', 't', 'T'] for sortedLst.

This is exactly what I am going for - to sort a word in alphabetical order with lower case letters taking precedence over upper case.

What I am trying to achieve is to match other 8-letter inputs by sorting them in the exact way that I have sorted ThatCcher. How would I go about achieving this?

EDIT: I am being told the question is unclear - my apologies but it is a bit difficult to explain so I will try again.

By sorting ThatCcer to become acCehrtT, lst[0] ('T') took the position of sortedLst[7], lst[1] ('h') took the position of sortedLst[4], and so on...

This is the history I want to record and so that given any other string can copy the steps that 'ThatCcer' took, for example: `s = ['h', 'o', 'w', 'e', 'v', 'e', 'r', 's']` I want s[0] to to take its' position in sortedS[7], just like ThatCcer did.

I hope this made it a little clearer!

Comment: Your question is very unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you want to achieve a behavior similar to that of [`numpy.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html).

You can sort a range based on your criteria, and use it to reindex any string:

```
lst =  ['T', 'h', 'a', 't', 'C', 'c', 'e', 'r']
idx = list(range(len(lst)))
sorted_idx = sorted(idx, key=lambda x: (lst[x].lower(), lst[x].swapcase()))
# [2, 5, 4, 6, 1, 7, 3, 0]

# now use the index to sort
[lst[i] for i in sorted_idx]
# ['a', 'c', 'C', 'e', 'h', 'r', 't', 'T']

# keep the same order on another string
lst2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
[lst2[i] for i in sorted_idx]
# ['c', 'f', 'e', 'g', 'b', 'h', 'd', 'a']
```

Another approach using `zip`:

```
lst =  ['T', 'h', 'a', 't', 'C', 'c', 'e', 'r']
lst2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']

list(zip(*sorted(zip(lst, lst2), key=lambda x: (x[0].lower(), x[0].swapcase()))))

# or as individual lists
# (lst_sorted, lst2_sorted) = list(zip(*sorted(zip(lst, lst2),
#                               key=lambda x: # (x[0].lower(), x[0].swapcase()))))
```

output:

```
[('a', 'c', 'C', 'e', 'h', 'r', 't', 'T'),
 ('c', 'f', 'e', 'g', 'b', 'h', 'd', 'a')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort the enumerated string on the string characters, then separate the (*sorted*) indices and characters; use [operator.itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to create a callable that you can re-use.

```
import operator
def f(thing):
    s_lst = sorted(enumerate(thing),key = lambda x: (x[1].lower(), x[1].swapcase()))
    argsort = operator.itemgetter(*[x[0] for x in s_lst])
    s_lst = [x[1] for x in s_lst]
    return s_lst,argsort
```

---

```
>>> s_lst, argsort = f('ThatCcerCTaa')
>>> s_lst
['a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'C', 'C', 'e', 'h', 'r', 't', 'T', 'T']
>>> argsort('ThatCcerCTaa')
('a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'C', 'C', 'e', 'h', 'r', 't', 'T', 'T')
>>> argsort
operator.itemgetter(2, 10, 11, 5, 4, 8, 6, 1, 7, 3, 0, 9)
>>>
```

Comment: Using `list.index` repeatedly to find back the indices will be very inefficient as you have to read many times the list. Also this will fail in case you have duplicates, only the first one will be found.

Comment: You are right, i didn't think about duplicates. It can be fixed....but it might be ugly